# How can I write a cfloop with dynamic index from file upload

Tags: loops, coldfusion

I have the following code that is reading a spreadsheet in a file upload.
My question is: How do i make COL_3 dynamic so the 3 is the index number of the loop?
So something like:

```
<cfset test = test & variables.file.COL_[j][j]>
```

but this doesnt work. 
This is what I have:

```
<cfset ColQty  = #ListLen(variables.file.ColumnList)#>
<cfset test = "">
  <cfloop from="1" to="#ColQty#" index="j">
      <cfset test = test & variables.file.COL_3[j]>     
  </cfloop>
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks
JC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access struct keys like this:

```
<cfset test = test & variables.file["COL_" & j][j]>
```

But I expect your code will behave incorrectly since you're not resetting `test` each time, so it will just keep appending over and over.

Comment: Thanks that works fine, thats ok I need to build a list for the test variable value.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#ColQty#" index="j">
    <cfset test = test & variables.file["COL_" & j][j]>     
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I now see this error when i apply your suggestion: Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.